# How to - Improving my code performance to get unique value from array - Javascript

Tags: javascript, performance

my code speed performance very slow when to get unique value from array that existing 5000 users data.


There is my code below which has two conditions:

First, to get unique value

Second, to check phone number is null or not, given preference to users data that existing phone number/s.

```
var arr = [
  ["Wong", ""],
  ["Wong", "0143213123"],
  ["Ali", "0177213123"],
  ["Ali", "0177213123, 0124545345"],
  ["Ali", ""],
  ["Imran", "0133454335"]
];

function uniq(arr) {
  var seen = [];
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var a = arr[i][0];
    var a2 = arr[i][1];
    var c = true;
    for (x = 0; x < seen.length; x++) {
      var b = seen[x][0];
      var b2 = seen[x][1];
      if (b == a) {
        c = false;
        if ((b2.trim() == '' || b2.indexOf(',') == -1) && (a2.trim() != '')) {
          seen[x][1] = a2.trim();
          break;
        }
        break;
      }
    }
    if (c == true) {
      seen.push(arr[i]);
    }

  }
  return seen;
}
```

Result, after code executed:

```
var arr = uniq(arr);
console.log(arr);

[
  ["Wong", "0143213123"],
  ["Ali", "0177213123, 0124545345"],
  ["Imran", "0133454335"]
];
```

**In jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7mjvfwpg/74/)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this with reduce and store data in one object for each name.

```js
var arr = [["Wong",""], ["Wong", "0143213123"], ["Ali", "0177213123"], ["Ali", "0177213123, 0124545345"], ["Ali", ""], ["Imran", "0133454335"]];

var uniq = arr.reduce((r, [name, number]) => {
  if(!r[name] || number.trim().length) r[name] = number;
  return r;
}, {});

console.log(Object.entries(uniq))
```

Comment: Thank @Nenad Vracar , i will test  and feedback later (y)